# Coverage data without system header files in QNX

Tags: file, header, code-coverage, gcov, qnx

I have generated gcno and gcda files required for code coverage.
After importing these files into `QNX IDE`, it shows code coverage for all system included header files (like `<vector>`) also whose values are `zero%`.

Is there any `option`/`flags` while build to remove system header files from code coverage data in `QNX IDE`.

Comment: Please let me know is there any way to solve above.